# Blinking image in table cell

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I want to have a blinking image (swaps between two images) in table cells.

What seemed most natural to me is as follows:

- Set a NSTimer to goes every .5 seconds, calling -blink:
- In -blink: I toggle a blinkStatus variable on/off
- In -cellForRowAtIndexPath:, I set the image depending upon the blinkStatus

Now, I also call [myTableView reloadData] in the -blink: method, so thinks get updated.

This seems to make sense; the state of the cells *is* actually changing (the image is being changed), so having the table update makes sense.

This works.  *However*, the reloadData seems to interfere with the user interaction:

In table editing mode if the user selects (-) to delete, and the Delete button appears, it will disappear when reloadData occurs.  It's easy enough only do the reloadData if [myTableView.editing] is false.  (And it's not a big problem to not have blinking during editing mode.)

However, the reloadData still seems to mess things up (e.g. clear cell selection).  I also worry about the efficiency of calling reloadData every .5 seconds.

Is there a smoother way to get that image blinking?  I was thinking of saving a pointer to any blinking cells, and update the .image property in the timer.  But this seems like a bad idea, since cells are reused for different rows of the table (ouch), and I doubt that simply updating the .image property would update the table without a reloadData.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to use `[UIImageView animationImages]` property? 
Just provide your images, set required duration and animationRepeatCount and call startAnimating

Comment: This worked like a charm.  Thanks!  (Bonus points if you can tell me how to sync up the blinking between multiple cells.)

Answer (score 2):

You should just toggle the image in the `-blink` method, as long as you use the proper interfaces ( such as `cell.imageView.image` ) then the image will update automatically, no need to call `reloadData`

Comment: But if the user scrolls, a reusable cell object might be reused for displaying other data, so any cell.imageView.image won't be referring to the right thing.  I'd be blinking the same reused cell, not the same data.

Comment: You pass `indexPath` for the given cell to the `blink` method, and in there you call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to get the correct cell instance

Comment: I think this is incorrect.  cellForRowAtIndexPath is solely for the system to call to allocate/reuse/populate UITableCell's for display purposes, not for the main code to call.  (Doing so will get you a cell of your own, but not something that is useful nor displayed by the system.)  Even if you hung onto a pointer to a UITableCell, it'll get reused on scrolling, and you'd be blinking the wrong thing.

Comment: When you call it directly on the tableview you get the actual cell instance.  When the tableview calls it on the data source it allocates or dequeues a new instance